# Use SimpleHTTPServer to store a cookie value

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am using SimpleHTTPServer to host a bunch of html files using

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The html files contain javascript that uses a cookie to identify a visitor. The javascript sets the cookie if one is not present and reads it otherwise. I want to store the value of the cookie on the server (perhaps, on a text file) on each visit. How can I do this?